# Hide a horizontal scrollbar inside a div while being able to scroll

Tags: html, css

I want to hide the horizontal scrollbar inside a div that's too wide, because it looks kinda ugly. I do still want to be able to scroll. Example:

[image]

My HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
  <span class="nav"><a class="nav-current" href="index.html">About me</a></span>
  <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span>
  <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span> <!-- Copied those to test the behaviour -->
  <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span>
  <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span>
</div>
```

The corresponding CSS:

```
div.nav {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you point to a site that visually agrees with what you are trying to accomplish.  Several folks here threw answers at you but it will help them if you provided a real time site with the end goal.

Answer (score 2):

The trick to hide a scroll bar is to use absolutely positioned elements.

Example:

```
<div class="scrollbar-hider-container">
    <div class="nav-container">    
        <div class="nav">
            <span class="nav"><a class="nav-current" href="index.html">About me</a></span>
            <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span>
            <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span> <!-- Copied those to test the behaviour -->
            <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span>
            <span class="nav"><a class="nav" href="biography.html">Biography</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.nav {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -30px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.scrollbar-hider-container {
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
```

For the best results you can calculate the actual height of the scrollbar used on the browser with js:

```
scrollBarWidth = function() {
        var scrollBarWidth = 0,
            scrollDiv = document.createElement('div');

        scrollDiv.className = 'scrollbar-measure';
        document.body.appendChild(scrollDiv);

        scrollBarWidth = scrollDiv.offsetWidth - scrollDiv.clientWidth;
        document.body.removeChild(scrollDiv);

        return scrollBarWidth;
    }
```

css:

```
.scrollbar-measure {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: -9999px;
}
```

with the scrollbar width you can then adjust the position of the scrolling element inside the div with the overflow hidden.

Answer (score 0):

To hide both scrollbars (X and Y) add this rule:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Comment: Why not simply change overflow-y to overflow?

Comment: @Alex That will affect both overflow-x and overflow-y but you're right, that's exactly what we want, in this case.

Comment: @Guy3000 If I do that, I'm not able to scroll anymore at all. I want to be able to scroll, but I want to  hide the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Y is vertical and X is horizontal. overflow-y: hidden will resolve.

Comment: I'm already using that, but I want to be able to hide the ugly scrollbar it causes, while being able to scroll.

Comment: If you want to hide for certain sizes, just use media queries, then you'll guess when is time to hide the scroll or not.

Answer (score 0):

change `overflow-y: hidden;` with `overflow-x: hidden;`

Comment: If I do that, the scrollbar will become vertical instead of horizontally, so that's not how I want it.